# Bandcamp delay using Safari

Tags: macos, safari, performance

When trying to play a song on Bandcamp, there is either a long delay before the it starts or it does not start at all. The song buffers (as indicated by the spinning animation) and then I see the pause button as if it were playing but it is not. On other browsers, it works just fine.

Safari is 13.1 on macOS 10.15.4

Any ideas as to why this happens and how to fix it?